# How to extract a fixed number of frames from videos of different duration using ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, ffmpeg-php

I want to get 8 frames from every video file which have variable duration. I am not going to get  8 frames from start i want to get from whole video starting to end of video.
Is anyone know php-library for accomplished that ?

Comment: ffmpeg -i input.mkv -vf select='not(mod(n\,300))',setpts=N/TB -r 1 -s 720*720 -vframes 8 output/frames%03d.png

Comment: after lots of struggle i create a command but its only valid of short videos it gets only 8 frames in the begging of long video.

Comment: See [this ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8679390/ffmpeg-extracting-20-images-from-a-video-of-variable-length ) or [this][2] questions. Doing a search yields some more. [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35912335/how-to-extract-a-fixed-number-of-frames-with-ffmpeg